# Derive type from object keys in function parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

**Some context**

I'm  making a form (using [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form)), and spying on some of the form's state.

The library provides a React component (`FormSpy`) that lets you subscribe to changes in various parts of the form's state, and calls a callback function with only those parts of the form's state (which are never `null` or `undefined`) when the form state does change.

**A simplified version of the code in question**

```
// Represents the current state of the form.
// values is an object with each field in the form as a key
// submitting is true if a submission is currently in progress
type FormState = {
 values?: Object,
 submitting?: boolean,
};

// Indicate which form state changes to subscribe to
type Subscription = {
 values?: boolean, 
 submitting?: boolean, 
};

type RenderCallback = (formState: FormState) => React.Node;

// The function that is automatically called with the subscribed-to parts of the form state when something changes
function FormSpy(subscription: Subscription, render: RenderCallback) {
 // This is available to the component
 const relevantFormState = getRelevantFormStateBySubscription(subscription);

 // Call the callback with the relevant form state
 return render(relevantFormState);
}
```

… and to only subscribe to changes to the form's `values` (not `submitting` state), you can use it like this (assuming that the form has a field called "email" with the value "test@test.xyz":

```
function renderEmail = ({ values: { email }}) {
 return <div>{email}</div>;
}

const theSpy = (
  <FormSpy
   subscription={{ values: true }}
   renderCallback={renderEmail}
 />
);
```

**My problem**

As humans reading the code, we know that `values` will be an object, because we just subscribed to `values`.

However, `values` is a `Maybe` type in the `FormState` type, so Flow forces us to check that `values` exists before accessing anything in it (in this case, picking out `email`).

This works fine, but is unnecessarily bloated:

```
function renderEmail({ values }) {
   if (values == null) {
    throw new Error('This never happens because of our subscription');
   }

   return <div>{values.email}</div>;
}

const theSpy = (
 <FormSpy
  subscription={{ values: true }}
  renderCallback={renderEmail}
 />
);
```

I could also go around the problem by putting a `// $FlowFixMe` above the line where I destructure `values`, but that also mutes all other errors on that line and doesn't solve my problem.

**My question**

Is it possible to use the object keys in the `subscription` parameter to derive a type that can be used as a parameter type for `renderCallback`, so that we don't have to perform these unnecessary null/undefined checks?

That is, given a `subscription` with `values: true`, I want to create a specialised version of `FormState` like `{ values: Object }`, rather than `{ values?: Object, submitting?: booolean }`.

The keys always always have the same name in the `subscription` and the `values`—I'm not sure if that matters.

Can this be done?

Comment: Pragmatically: maybe just create a helper method that wraps the value with a null check and throws the error? Or use something like invariant?

Comment: @JamesKraus I could definitely create a helper (and it looks like that's where I'm headed), but since this is a library and my decision here will affect other developers in my organisation, I would like to fix the "root cause". Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean when you say "use something like invariant", please?

Comment: There's a library called invariant ( https://github.com/zertosh/invariant ) that's basically for asserting stuff like this. Not sure that it's really needed though. You could just as easily write your own little helper without all the fuss. Anyways, I hope you find a good solution to this!

Comment: I can't really inspect this stuff on my machine without a reproducable example, so do you know why the `values` property is typed as `null` even though you expect it to always have a value?

Comment: @JamesKraus ah, thanks! I want to fail in the type checks though, not runtime.

`values` (like all other parts of the FormState) has a maybe type because it is possible to "subscribe" on any combination of pieces of the FormState. In my example, the `subscription` might contain only `{ submitting: true }`, which means that the component will be rendered with the props `{ values: undefined, submitting: false }` (or `submitting: true` if that's the case). That's why I want to look at the keys in the `subscription` to know which props are going to be present :)

Comment: There's a lot of moving pieces in your question. If you want to throw up a github repo with a MVP, I'll at least look at it.